# microservices: client service and server service (fastAPI) running as docker

Tags: python, docker, microservices, client-server, fastapi

I need to build a small program with microservice architecture:

1. server service (Python fast API framework)

I run it with Dockerfile command:

```
 CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

2. client service: simple Python CLI textual requires input as username from input CLI and to connect server GET/POST HTTP requests

```
unsername= input("Please insert your unsername:")
log.info(f"{unsername}")
```

I run it with Dockerfile command:

```
CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

I am not sure how to run my client with the docker to run the main but with no existing.
when I am running with venv from 2 different terminals the client and the server all work as expected and succeed to connect (because both of them are on my machine)
with docker.

1. I got an error related to the username I try to input
   EOFError: EOF when reading a line
2. even if delete the input I still got an error conn = connection.create_connection...Failed to establish a new connection like the client failed to connect my server when it on isolated container.

Comment: If your error is about connecting between the client and the server, what are you actually trying to connect to, and how are you launching the two components?  A tool that accepts interactive input can be a little tricky to run in Docker; would it make sense to run the server in a container, but the CLI tool directly on the host system?

Comment: I need to run CLI client as a container and the server service with another container. the client trying to get HTTP request from server. it works on my host after I add to client code  with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:8000/api/docs'):

Comment: If you're running the client in a container, `localhost` is the client container, not the server container or the host system.

Answer (score 0):

for enable input from terminal need to adding to docker-compose :

```
tty: true # docker run -t
stdin_open: true # docker run -i
```